# How to store ISO 8601 Datetime in Sequelizejs

Tags: datetime, sequelize.js, iso8601

I'm trying to store UTC ISO 8601 datetime objects in Sequelize 4.0 however I can only specify DateType.Date in my models. When I use in a formatted ISO 8601 datetime string when inserting data I get a parse error:

```
"Incorrect datetime value: '2018-05-14T14:29:21.338Z' for column 'columnName' at row 1"
```

My model looks like the following (simplified for question):

```
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  var deviceData = sequelize.define('deviceData', {
    steps: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    recordedOn: DataTypes.DATE,
    batteryLevel: DataTypes.INTEGER,
  }, {});

  return deviceData;
};
```

Database config looks like;

```
module.exports = {
  development: {
    database: 'DATABASENAME',
    username: 'MYUSERNAME',
    password: 'MYPASSWORD',
    dialect: 'mysql',
    host: 'HOSTNAME'
  },
  testing: {
    dialect: 'sqlite',
    storage: ':memory:',
    logging: false
  }
};
```

And I declare my Sequelize instance as follows:

```
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');

const basename = path.basename(__filename);
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');
let config = require('../config/db.js');

const db = {};
db.sequelize = new Sequelize(config.database, config.username, config.password, config);
db.Sequelize = Sequelize; 

module.exports = db;
```

I can't decide if I should parse all ISO 8601 datetime objects into datetime objects before I insert into the db or whether Sequelize offers to ability to interpret ISO 8601 datetime objects alongside datetime objects in my db.

Comment: Sequelize still doesn't allow storing dates without timezones.